# Por qué los estilos no cambian en "dark-mode"

Tags: css

estoy haciendo una web con material design, una libreria bastante basica (materialize), no uso material.io ni material-ui.com porque con mi host no puedo y al poner la función de "dark-mode" los estilos de la pagina cambian normalmente, menos los del material design, y no logro que cambie.
[image: MODO OSCURO]
[image: Modo normal]
Les dejo la funcion JS del darkmode, y algunos codigos del CSS:

**Javascript:**

```
function fuctiondarkmode() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

   if (document.body.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
    localStorage.setItem('dark-mode','true');
   }else{
    localStorage.setItem('dark-mode','false');
   }
}
if (localStorage.getItem('dark-mode') === 'true') {
  document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
}else{
  document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn, .btnoutline, .btn-large, .btn-small, .btn-floating, .btn-large, .btn-small, .btn-flat {
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: 0;
}
.btn, .btnoutline, .btn-large, .btn-small {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #02487c;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-out;
    transition: background-color .2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.waves-effect {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-out;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}
```

No se si les sirve eso, si necesitan algo mas me avisan y lo agrego, aunque tambien se puede ver en materialize, es basicamente la misma libreria.

No se me ocurre nada